# How to create a timeseries of 99-percentiles from Loki in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have a server application logging all HTTP response times to Loki. I would like to generate time series of 99-percentile response times for each endpoint to see trends and problems. The following query is similar to what I see recommended:

```
quantile_over_time(0.99,{filename="/var/log/server.log"}
    | json
    | MessageTemplate=~".*HostingRequestFinishedLog:l.*"
    | unwrap Properties_ElapsedMilliseconds[1m])
  by (Properties_Path)
```

However, this just generates a single datapoint per endpoint (path), for instance like this:

[image]

The endpoints shown here have requests each minute, so should have enough data to populate a line graph.

How can I turn the request into time series?

Comment: hi, are you doing an instant query or a range query? You'll need a range query.

Comment: Hi. I should have mentioned that yes, I'm doing a range query. Thanks.

Comment: that's strange, something might be off in your time series chart properties, Can you try changing your range with `$__interval`? i.e.  unwrap Properties_ElapsedMilliseconds[$__interval])

Comment: That didn't fix it, but it pointed me to the issue! Interval was overridden in "Query options" to 24 hours, which is why I only saw one datapoint. Thanks for pointing me there!